# Log4Net how to log

Tags: log4net, exit, enter

I am new with log4net and am wondering how to properly be able to log. I have seen examples of people doing Logs.Enter, Logs.Exit. It properly logs and helps users when testing/debugging. Examples of how to define is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You define a log4net log like so:

```
private static log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogName"]);
```

I defined it so that it is defined in app config. Afterwards, I define methods to determine the type of log i.e. Error, Info, Enter, Exit etc.

Enter/Exit method example:

```
    [Conditional("ENTEREXIT")]
    public static void Enter()
    {
        _log.Info(GetMethodName() + ": In");
    }

    [Conditional("ENTEREXIT")]
    public static void Exit()
    {
        _log.Info(GetMethodName() + ": Out");
    }
```

Save this in a separate class called Logs.cs

Then, whenever you want to log, you simple do `Logs.Enter` and then stop logging with `Logs.Exit`. You can do `Logs.Info` or `Logs.Error` without the Enter/Exit Logs.